# add a colleague as azure b2c admin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I created a new azure B2C AD and linked it to my subscription.

Now I want another colleague to be able to access the B2C tenant, register apps and edit ones I registered.

In the portal, I can switch directory to the B2C directory, however, when I tried to add the colleague as a new member to the AD of the directory it said their email (which is a member of the original subscription)  is not a verified domain name for this directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new Azure portal, this experience has changed a bit. You will need to invite your colleague using the "New guest user" link. Once invitation has been sent, you an add them as a Global Administrator.

The invited guest will get an email with the invitation link. Once they click it and redeem the invite, they will have access to the directory as an administrator.

[image: all users screenshot]

[image: a new guest user screenshot]

Find the user and open it.

[image: change directory role screenshot]

Comment: how do I invite them?  when I try to use add user I get the error In the question (i.e. email is not a verified domain name for this directory)

Comment: You must choose Azure AD B2C > Users and groups > All users > New guest user.

Comment: Thank you Chris for clarifying this. I updated my response to reflect the "new guest user" link better.